# How to get total of a field for all the nodes?

Tags: 7, views

I've `payment` content type. One of the fields of this content-type is `Amount`. In a view (page display: table format) I'm listing all the payment nodes (subjected to some filtering). In the same view I want to calculate the total amount amount of all these filtered nodes & display. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) or, if you need more flexibility, [Views Aggregator Plus](https://drupal.org/project/views_aggregator)